# extra pit next to sump pump

Tags: drainage, sump-pump

I have a basement with a properly installed sump pump.
I have another hole approximately 1 foot away from the sump hole cut to the same dimensions.  There are at least 2 pipes that run into the unused hole that I thought were for drainage but the hole holds water. The sump pump and extra hole do not connect.

What is the second hole supposed to be used for?  Should I fill it in?

Comment: Radon collection and exhaust never completed?

Comment: Could be for a backup sump system. Some folks prefer two pails and isolated hardware.

Comment: "2 pipes that run into the unused hole": where do they come from?

Comment: Do you mean you've observed  the water level does not drop when the pump runs?

Comment: With a backup pump, it's common to have this arrangement, although there will be a bucket in each pit. Often, there is a pipe connecting the two pits just below the floor.  If the primary pump fails, its pit will overflow into the secondary and be pumped out there.  It's simple to provide for these pits at the time the floor is poured.  If the second pit is just a hole filled with water, it sounds like the builder never finished installing the full system.  A radon pit isn't typically put right next to a sump pit because it will suck air from the other pit rather than the void under the floor.

Comment: If pipes run into the hole, it could be a perimeter drain system.  In any event, the water is coming from somewhere, and you don't want it there.  I would install a sump bucket in the hole and tie the pipes into it.  Put a sump pump in the bucket and pipe it out like the other one, discharging as far from your house as practical.